# Regex to match repeated substring in Google Sheets

Tags: string, google-sheets

I have data that always starts with a substring repeated twice without a delimiter, and then other data that I don't care about. The length of the repeated substring varies, and in the example below I'm using mostly [a-z] characters for the sake of simplicity, but the repeated substring is mostly unicode squiggles in the real dataset.

| my data | what I want to extract |
| --- | --- |
| `johnjohnsajoalsas` | `john` |
| `peterpeteraaksoskco` | `peter` |
| `a8co.a8co.robinson` | `a8co.` |
| `robrob7s:s7` | `rob` |
| `dkoisawks` | `\[null\]` |

This can be done easily with a positive lookahead

```
^(.+)(?=\1)
```

or directly referencing the capture group like this

```
^(.+)\1
```

However, Google Sheets doesn't support either of these.

Any help will be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: What can SO do for you when Google Sheets doesn't support it ?

Comment: A [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aU1R62/1)  which seems to indicate that your regex is OK ....

Comment: I hope there might be other ways to solve my problem that do work on Google Sheets. I thought this was implicit in my question.

Comment: Maybe you can export your Google Sheets to other formats then you use regex on them, however, I don't know if Google Sheets is exportable.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll try Microsoft Excel (I think they also support Regex) and come back with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here's one approach (**`non-regex`**) you may test out in Sheets:*

```js
=let(Λ,A2, Σ,map(sequence(rounddown(len(Λ)/2)),lambda(Σ,{left(Λ,Σ),left(Λ,Σ)=mid(Λ,Σ+1,Σ)})),
    ifna(+filter(Σ,index(Σ,,2)),"-"))
```

[image]

- lists all probabilities using **`left()`** and **`mid()`** to filter out the
  possible match if any...

Comment: Holy Moly. This did the trick. And I thought I was good with spreadsheet built-in functions till I saw your answer. My jaw dropped and I can't make it un-drop

Answer (score 0):

I had a try with *Google Sheets* and used "*search and replace*" with
`^(.{2,})\1(.*)$` and it worked.

I tested `(.*)\1` and also `(.*?)\1` as you mentioned, and effectively
it doesn't work.

It should also work with `^(.+?)\1`. So the problem was just that
`*` would match zero times and `+` would force at least to match one
char.

So up to you to decide, but I think that a first name should be
probably more than 2 characters, so this is why I would prefer using
`.{2,}` or even `\S{2,}` to be sure to match non-spaces.

**Search**: `^(\S{2,})\1(.*)$`

**Replace**: `$1`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```cpp
=LET(s,SEQUENCE(INT(LEN(A2)/2)),FILTER(LEFT(A2,s),LEFT(A2,s)=MID(A2,s+1,s)))
```

[image]

The idea is the same as the other user. Generate all the potentially matching strings of length at most `INT(LEN(str)/2)` and only keep the ones that match, if there are any.

For example, for `johnjohnsajoalsas` we check the following strings:

[image]

We see there is a match at row 4 so we keep that value and remove everything else.

We could also do this with a single formula in <kbd>C2</kbd> that doesn't require to be dragged using the [`MAP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en) function.

```cpp
=MAP(A2:A,LAMBDA(str,IF(str="",,LET(s,SEQUENCE(INT(LEN(str)/2)),
   FILTER(LEFT(str,s),LEFT(str,s)=MID(str,s+1,s))))))
```

[image]